# what is the name of this small plant with yellow flower?

Tags: botany, flowers

Can someone please help me find the name of this flower. The close I got to is maybe some kind of diasy?.
[image]
[image]

Location: Hyderabad, India

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like ***Sphagneticola trilobata*** also known as Singapore daisy, creeping-oxeye, trailing daisy, and wedelia.  It is now found throughout the Neotropics but is native to Mexico, Central America, and the Carribean.  It is a weed that is classified in the top 100 worst invasive species in the world.

[image]

Source: [***Sphagneticola trilobata*** (ePlants)](http://www.eplants.com.au/singapore-daisy/)

Comment: Thank you very much Kurt for your answer. It's funny though, how Mexican native species got the name of Singapore daisy.